# java array creation complication

Tags: java, python, arrays

being new to java after having coded only in languages such as python and javascript, the best way to describe my issue is with an example from one of those two languages. to start with the error i am getting for my java program is when i attempt to create an array directly, such as `string[] narray = {{'test',1}, {'test', 2}, {'test', 3}}` now doing something like this gave me an illegal initialization error so i changed it to `Array[][] narray = {{'test',1}, {'test', 2}, {'test', 3}}` yet it is now giving me a "cannot find symbol" error. i am at a bit of a loss as to how to create an array like this directly. in python all i would have to do is `narray = [['test', 1], ['test', 2], ['test', 3]]`. how would i define an array like this in java? thank you.

Comment: ["Java Arrays" on Google gets me this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: you forgot one more bracket, String[][] narray = {{'test',1}, {'test', 2}, {'test', 3}}

Comment: rod_algonquin that gives an incompatible types error "int and String"

Comment: @user3723955 instead of String use Object.

Comment: aha that worked. that is exactly what i was looking for, some way to create an array with both String and int

Comment: No. Arrays contain objects of the type that the array is declared to be, which means that if you have different objects in an array the array must be declared as one of the common supertypes to both objects. `String` and `int` have no supertypes in common, so no such thing is possible. `int` can be autoboxed to `Integer`, though, which share `Object` and `Serializable`.

Comment: `String[][] array = new String[][]  {{'test',1}, {'test', 2}, {'test', 3}};` try this one.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a HashMap for your particular case :

```
HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("foo",1);
map.put("bar",2);
map.put("baz",3);
```

If the values repeat themselfes then consider this pair object :

```
class Pair<F,S> {
    public final F first;
    public final S second;
    public Pair(F first,S second){
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
}

// in your method

List<Pair<String,Integer>> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(new Parir("foo",1);
myList.add(new Parir("bar",1);
myList.add(new Parir("foo",3);
```

since you made the jump to a type safe language you might as well start thinking in one

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for a `String[]` is off for Java, I believe you wanted something like this;

```
String[] narray = {"test", "test", "test"};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(narray));

// alternatively (using explicit indexes).    
String[] tmp = new String[2];
tmp[0] = "1";
tmp[1] = "2";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tmp));
```

When I run the above, I get (as expected)

```
[test, test, test]
[1, 2]
```